# Finding a string of varying length within parentheses that contain parentheses

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I want to take a string input (that may vary) that will have some form

```
aString = "foo1(bar1(foo2bar2)) foo3(bar3)"
```

I want to use some sort of regular expression that will return

```
[[foo1, (bar1(foo2bar2))], [foo3, (bar3)]]
```

The actual string will consist of letters, numbers, white space and parentheses.  I first split it up by white space using `aString.split()` and then want to split each part by the outer parentheses.  What I have so far is this:

```
import re

aString = "foo1(bar1(foo2bar2)) foo3(bar3)"
aList = aString.split()
newList = []
for part in aList:
    index1 = part.find('(')
    index2 = part.rfind(')')
    aLen = index2 - index1 - 1
    prog = re.compile(r'(\(.{,aLen}\))')
    newList.append(prog.split(part))

print newList
```

which returns this:

```
[['foo1(bar1(foo2bar2))'], ['foo3(bar3)']]
```

My understanding of this form of regular expression was that `.` would match all strings, and `{,aLen}` would match between zero and `aLen` repetitions of the previous regular expression, in this case `.` or all strings.  However as you can see, it doesn't appear to do that because running

`newList.append(prog.match(part))` instead of `newList.append(prog.split(part))`

returns `[None, None]`

I don't have a lot of experience with regular expressions so it is certainly possible that I am misunderstanding what the different regular expressions mean or how they work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So what you want is something that takes a Fname(args) and converts it to [[fname, args],[other_fname, [nested_fname, args]], etc...] ?

Comment: @OmegaOuter No. I want to take a string of the form shown above, or in the comments of the answer below, and return the interior of all parentheses without removing the parentheses. The location and number of parentheses will vary (they will always open and close) and the content/length of the area between the parentheses will vary.

Comment: Well I did read the comments below, and I sincerely the expected outcome of both is different. In the Original question you dont do nested traversin were as in the one below you do, and in the first you might take an arbitrary number of expressions. I think that you should edit the original question to address the exact behaviour you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, you could probably get away with *not* using regex at all. If you only need to perform this splitting operation once, you could probably use `string.partition` to simply split by the first occurrence of the outer parenthesis.

```
def parse(string):
    front, paren, back = string.partition('(')
    return [front, paren + back]

def parse_many(string):
    return [parse(s) for s in string.split()]

aString = "foo1(bar1(foo2bar2)) foo3(bar3)"
print parse_many(aString)
```

However, if your input is more complex then this (if you were trying to implement some kind of parser), then you might want to look into using an actual parsing library such as pyparsing.

If you *do* want to use regex, then the following should work:

```
import re

aString = "foo1(bar1(foo2bar2)) foo3(bar3)"
aList = aString.split()
newList = []
for part in aList:
    prog = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(.*)')
    newList.append(prog.split(part)[1:3])

print newList
```

In this case, the regex is first matching any sequence of letters and numbers, then will match everything else. Note that this regex does not attempt to verify if the string following the initial word is enclosed in parenthesis, and does not attempt to verify if the number of parenthesis are correctly matching. As a result, the regex *could* end up being too lenient, and match strings that are not valid, depending on your particular use-case.

Comment: Well the input string could feasibly become rather complex, of some form `foo1bar1(foo2bar2(foo3bar3(foo4bar4(foo5bar5))))` or `foo1bar1(foo2bar2(foo3bar3(foo4bar4)foo5bar5(foo6bar6)))` or something else along those lines.  I would still be wanting to separate the string as before, so in the first case `[foo1bar1, [(foo2bar2, [(foo3bar3, [(foo4bar4, [(foo5bar5)], ')'], ')'], ')'], ')']`. In this case would you recommend using a parsing library or some sort of recursive function that uses regex?

Comment: @Dannnno -- are there ever going to be commas? For example, would the string ever resemble something like `f1(a1, f2(a2, a3), f4(f5(a1)))`?

Comment: @Dannnno -- is it required that you retain the parenthesis in the final output, in that precise configuration, or is it acceptable if they were removed?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure.  I haven't actually written the part of the code that handles the parentheses yet.

It would probably be fine if they were removed.